# WPF ObservableCollection & Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wpftoolkit

I am trying to add a list of items to my Listview using ObservableCollection.
when I build , I get this error in the line 2:  "StudentCollection" as follows:

```
  Inconsistent accessibility: property type System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<HMSystem.ChildPage1.studentData>' is  less accessible than property 'SHSystem.ChildPage1.studentCollection' d:\data\visual studio 2010\Projects\SSSystem\SHSystem\ChildPage1.xaml.cs
```

here is what I  have tried so far,

```
    // created a property 
    private ObservableCollection<studentData> _StudentCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<studentData> StudentCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_StudentCollection== null)
            {
                _StudentCollection= new ObservableCollection<studentData>();
            }
            return _StudentCollection;
        }
    }

    //created a class for studentData
    class studentData
    {
        public string StudentName{ get; set; }
        public string Class{ get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

in the constructor :

```
         public ChildPage1()
         {
          _StudentCollection.Add(new studentData{ StudentName = "Arun", Class= "tenth", Status = "Active" });
         _StudentCollection.Add(new studentData{ StudentName = "Priya", Class= "ninth", Status = "Active" });
          InitializeComponent();
         }
```

in XAML :

```
        <ListView Height="96" Name="listView1" Width="226" ItemsSource="{Binding  ElementName=Page1,Path=StudentCollection}">
             <ListView.View>
              <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Name"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StudentName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Class" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Class}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" />
              </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
       </ListView>
```

any ideas ??
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your collection `StudentCollection` is public and your class `studentData` is private. Just make it public:

```
public class studentData
{
    public string StudentName{ get; set; }
    public string Class{ get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```